# SQLで年月別に集計したデータを縦に積み重ねて一つのテーブルとして出力したい

Tags: mysql, sql

タイトルの通り年月別にデータを集計して積み重ねて一つのテーブルにしたいと考えています
使用しているデータベースはMySQL 5.7.12 です

**【質問の詳細】**

次のようなデータがあります

| 契約日 | 契約ID | 解約日 | 契約の種類 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-12 | 001 | 2021-07-21 | 1 |
| 2021-03-17 | 002 | 2022-02-04 | 3 |
| 2021-03-19 | 003 | 2022-02-24 | 1 |
| ︙ | ︙ | ︙ |  |
| 2022-03-24 | 999 | NULL | 2 |

連番の年月(仮に基準年月と名付けます)を用意して、その基準年月をもとに特定の条件で抽出したテーブルを次のように積み重ねたいと思います。

| 基準年月 | 契約日 | 契約ID | 解約日 | 契約の種類 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 2021-03-12 | 001 | 2021-07-21 | 1 |
| 2021-01 | 2021-03-19 | 003 | 2022-02-24 | 1 |
| ︙ | ︙ | ︙ | ︙ | ︙ |
| 2021-01 | 2022-03-24 | 999 | NULL | 2 |
| ︙ | ︙ | ︙ | ︙ | ︙ |
| 2022-03 | 2022-03-24 | 999 | NULL | 2 |

よろしければ方法を教えて下さい
よろしくおねがいします

Comment: 基準年月は別テーブルに存在するわけではなくてSQLで記述するときに、記述するということでしょうか？また「基準年月をもとに特定の条件」とはどのような条件でしょうか？

Comment: 具体的なクエリが思いつかないにしても、元データからどういったルールで結果に結びつくのかの説明が無いと回答が難しい気がします。(契約ID 002 が飛んでいるのはなぜなのか、意図が読み取れませんでした)